# Microsoft Graph API calendar/getSchedule POST request parameter

Tags: laravel, api, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams, microsoft-graph-calendar

Could anyone please explain how to use Microsoft Graph API's [calendar/getSchedule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-getschedule?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) request for application permission type?

I am using the the it in my app as a cronjob, means that i need to use 'POST /users/{id|userPrincipalName}/calendar/getSchedule' instead of 'POST /me/calendar/getSchedule' since the later requires a user to sign in.
My question is which user I should choose for {id|userPrincipalName}? Just random one from the list I want to check or just the admin id will do?

I have found a [github issue](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/13075) regarding this but no one has answered it yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any user or admin `id` on the condition that the `id` has a mailbox which enable them to access a calandar.